# Put text under a spinner bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.3 spinner, all working well but i want to put additional text under the spinner. Here is my HTML

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
               <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="row">
            <strong>Collecting data</strong>
        </div>
                            
    </div>
```

But the text "collecting data" is appending on the spinner, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add these two classes to the container div:

```
flex-column align-items-center
```

`flex-column` makes the flexbox stack vertically and `align-items-center` centers the items on the new axis.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
           <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <strong>Collecting data</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: GG, Thank you bro

Answer (score 3):

Problem is when you define your wrapping div class as `display:flex` it stack the inside elements as a columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
         <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <strong>Collecting data</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

`container` class will remove minus borders form row and `justify-content-center` will centered the items inside row

[Demo Code Pen](https://codepen.io/tharakauka/pen/KYzoQv)